# Complete files in a different directory in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

Does the compadd command for ZSH not support completion when some characters are entered？

I have a executable file called 'index_for_test.js',and i add a shell script to .zshrc.

$PATH: 
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/hanqing/Development/compadd-test`

the `index_for_test.js` at the root of `/Users/hanqing/Development/compadd-test`

```
./
├── dir1
│   ├── a.js
│   └── b.js
├── dir2
│   ├── a.ts
│   └── b.ts
└── index_for_test.js

total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 hanqing  staff   192 11  4 13:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 hanqing  staff   320 11  4 13:42 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 hanqing  staff  6148 11  4 14:04 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   4 hanqing  staff   128 11  4 13:43 dir1
drwxr-xr-x   4 hanqing  staff   128 11  4 13:43 dir2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 hanqing  staff   155 11  4 13:50 index_for_test.js
```

```js
// index_for_test.js
#! /usr/bin/env node

const fs =require('fs')
const path=require('path')
const files=fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd()))
console.log(files.join('\n'))
```

the script be added to .zshrc :

```sh
_index_for_test_completion() {
    local abc=(`index_for_test.js`)
    echo '\nabc:\n'
    echo $abc'\n'
    compadd -- $abc
}
compdef _index_for_test_completion index_for_test.js
```

When input `index_for_test.js` followed by input a space then press `tab`, it work find.But when input `index_for_test.js ../` then press `tab`,it does not show completion list, even if `compadd` accept the arguments.

### Image:

[normal: index_for_test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x7Rn.png)

[error: index_for_test.js ../](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq3DP.png)

### Expect

If this is my mistake,please let me know the reason,thanks.

In addition,if the behavior is right,I wonder that how to achieve completion like `cd` command;
[behavior of cd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcCpr.png)

Answer (score 0):

`index_for_test.js` only prints names of files in the *current* directory. A file name in the current directory cannot start with `../`, so there is no completion starting with `../`.

If you want to complete files in a directory, you need to pass this directory to your completion script, and have it work in that directory.

In addition, you should complete directory names inside zsh, if all directories may potentially contain interesting files. If you want to allow only certain directories, have your script complete directories.

In addition, your script is broken when file names contain whitespace. Use a null byte as the separator: file names can't contain null bytes.

Untested code. May need some tweaking.

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const files = fs.readdirSync(process.argv[2]);
console.log(files.join('\0'))
```

```sh
_index_for_test_completion() {
    local dir=$words[CURRENT] files
    if [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then dir=$dir:h; fi
    files=(${(ps:\0:)$(index_for_test.js $dir))
    print -lr '' abc: $files
    if [[ $dir != $words[CURRENT] ]]; then dir+="/"; fi
    compadd -- $^dir$files
}
compdef _index_for_test_completion index_for_test.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to zsh programming, i mistakenly thought `compadd` was just showing a list of word that i provided.Otherwise, I just understand part of the shell script you given, but got some watchful points from it, so I tried it for a long time, and then I combined the `-d` and `-S` arguments for `compadd` with `nodejs` to implement it.

Take the liberty to ask that can you introduce a place or a website where you can learn shell systematically?